# Полдень и полночь как стороны света

Tags: этимология

Интересно,а почему юг ассоциируется с полуднем, а север - с полуночью? В украинском эти стороны света так и называются: "пiвнiч" и "пiвдень".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В СЕВЕРНОМ ПОЛУШАРИИ "у полудня" была древняя географическая ассоциация с "югом" (также, как и полночь с "севером"). Остатки ассоциации "полудня" сохранены в словах в течение "полудня" на французском языке ("midi") и итальянский язык ("mezzogiorno"), ОБА ИЗ КОТОРЫХ ТАКЖЕ ОБРАЩАЮТСЯ К ЮЖНЫМ ЧАСТЯМ СООТВЕТСТВУЮЩИХ СТРАН. Современный польский и украинский язык делают шаг дальше, со словами в течение полудня ("południe", "південь" - буквально "неполным рабочим днем") также ЗНАЧЕНИЕ "на юг" и слова в течение "ПОЛУНОЧИ" ("północ", "північ" - буквально "полуночной") ТАКЖЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ "на север".

Answer (score 3):

Главной ориентационной системой в культурах Евразии являлась система, связанная с движением солнца. Соотнесение сторон света с ходом солнца встречается у большинства народов: Восток - восход, Запад - закат, Север - полночь, Юг-полдень.

На этом основаны и все сакральные действа:http://astro.rufox.ru/fengshui/86474.htm 
http://anabang.com/drevnyaya-mudrost

Понятие «мера дня», вероятно, использовалось в средневековом обозначении географических координат (широты или долготы) местности.
Широко известны такие названия как «полуденные» и «полуночные» страны (стороны).
«Полудённые страны» соответствуют направлению на юг (до экватора), где Солнце находится в 12 часов дня. При этом экватору соответствует нулевая широта или «полдень» (12 часов дня).
«Полуночные страны» соответствуют направлению на север (до полюса), где Солнце невидимо и находится в 12 часов ночи. При этом полюсу соответствует 90° широты или «полночь» (12 часов ночи).
В широтном промежутке от 0 до 90°, соответствующем времени суток от полудня до полуночи (от 12 часов дня до 12 часов ночи), расположены все остальные страны (стороны). Дневные, вечерние и ночные.
http://www.runitsa.ru/publications/publication_362.php